ChartJs.Blazor: Error Could not find a chart with the given id
I have just installed ChartJs.Blazor.Forked (0.2.0) and defined a pie chart. I took the sample from GitHub and adjusted it so I could populate the chart with data from an async service.
The odd part is that the chart will draw and draw correctly. But once it has drawn, then I receive this JSException.
Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find a chart with the given id. 247b9e4a-42ce-4ba3-9b1b-ebe8e90ebadc
   at Microsoft.JSInterop.JSRuntime.InvokeAsync[TValue](Int64 targetInstanceId, String identifier, Object[] args)
   at ChartJs.Blazor.Chart.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)

Blazor code:
                @if (isSetupComplete)
                {
                    <MudCard>
                        <MudCardHeader>
                            <MudText Typo="Typo.h5" Align="Align.Center" Style="color:steelblue"># of Patients by Gender</MudText>
                        </MudCardHeader>
                        <Chart Config="_pieConfig" @ref="_pieChart" Width="300" Height="300"></Chart>
                    </MudCard>
                }
            </MudItem>

C# code is:
        protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            await base.OnInitializedAsync();

            PageNotification.SetProcessing(true);
            try
            {
                #region Populate Data
                ...
                #endregion

                _pieConfig = new PieConfig
                {
                    Options = new PieOptions
                    {
                        Responsive = true,
                        Title = new OptionsTitle
                        {
                            Display = true,
                            Text = "# of Patients by Gender"
                        }
                    }
                };

                PieDataset<int> dataset = new PieDataset<int>(genderValues)
                {
                    BackgroundColor = new[]
                    {
                        ColorUtil.ColorHexString(255, 205, 86), // Slice 2 aka "Yellow"
                        ColorUtil.ColorHexString(54, 162, 235), // Slice 4 aka "Blue"
                    }
                };

                _pieConfig.Data.Datasets.Add(dataset);
                foreach (string gender in genderLabels)
                {
                    _pieConfig.Data.Labels.Add(gender);
                }

                PageNotification.StateChanged();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PageNotification.AddException(ex);
            }
        Done:
            isSetupComplete = true;
            PageNotification.SetProcessing(false);
        }


The answer turns out to be easy if not obvious. When I moved the definition of the config class to OnInitialized (not the async event) then everything works correctly.  The populate of the dataset(s) is still on OnInitializedAsync and the isSetupComplete flag enables the chart to be displayed.
